# AzureDevops pipeline task with condition not evaluated correctly

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I have a pipeline which checks whether a commit has a tag and if that tag is a Version tag (meaning it is like 'v1.0.0' or 'v01.00.00').

My problem is that when I save the result of the regex operation in a variable, it appears to first be `True` but when using it in the `condition` of the second task it is suddenly `False`.

Here is the pipeline:

```yaml
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  tags:
    include:
      - "*"

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

variables:
  hasTags: $[contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/')]
  isVersionTag: 'False'
  versionTag: ''

steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  condition: eq(variables.hasTags, 'True')
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # get the tag the from the SourcheBranch
      $dummy = $Env:Build_SourceBranch
      $regex = "(refs)\/(tags)\/(?<version_tag>.+)$"
      $result = [regex]::Matches($dummy, $regex)
      $Env:versionTag = $result[0].Groups["version_tag"].Value

      # check if the tag is actually a version (e.g. 'v1.0.1')
      $regex = "v[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}$"
      $Env:isVersionTag = [regex]::IsMatch($Env:versionTag, $regex)

      if($Env:isVersionTag -eq 'True')
      {
        Write-Host 'It is a version tag'
      }

      Write-Host "Variable Build.SourceBranch = $Env:Build_SourceBranch"
      Write-Host "Variable isVersionTag = $Env:isVerionTag"
      Write-Host "Variable hasTags = $Env:hasTags"
      Write-Host "Variable versionTag = $Env:versionTag"

# This will not run because the condition is evaluated as the following:
# Evaluating: and(eq(variables['hasTags'], 'True'), eq(variables['isVersionTag'], 'True'))
# Expanded: and(eq('True', 'True'), eq('False', 'True'))
# Result: False
- task: PowerShell@2
  condition: and(eq(variables.hasTags, 'True'), eq(variables.isVersionTag, 'True'))
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write your PowerShell commands here.
      
      Write-Host "The tag is a version tag"
```

The output of the `Write-Host` of the above pipeline is the following:

```
It is a version tag
Variable Build.SourceBranch = refs/tags/v02.01.07
Variable isVersionTag = 
Variable hasTags = True
Variable versionTag = v02.01.07
```

Answer (score 1):

The environment variables in PowerShell only contain strings, no booleans. In your case, they contain either the string "True" or the string "False". Either way, they contain something and the expression `$Env:isVersionTag` in the second example returns "False" which still is considered trueish. Use something like `if($Env:isVersionTag -eq "True")` instead, this should work.

To verify this behavior in any PowerShell window, you can do this:

```
$Env:testbool = $false
Write-Host $Env:testbool.GetType().FullName
```

Comment: While the first tasks runs now the second does not as the condition for the second task is not evaluated correctly. Do you know why that might be? I updated my question accordingly to show the new error.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up replacing

```
$Env:isVersionTag = [regex]::IsMatch($Env:versionTag, $regex)
```

with

```
if([regex]::IsMatch($Env:versionTag, $regex))
{
   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isVersionTag]True"
}else{
   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isVersionTag]True"
}
```

and then it worked as expected.

Comment: This would be the perfect answer, if in the else branch you would set the variable to "False" instead of also "True"